# feature selection and estimate the documents similarity in text mining

Tags: text-mining, similarity, feature-selection

I'm working on a text mining project by WEKA library in Java. In the preprocessing step I applied StringToWordVector filter. In this filter, I set several options like tokenizing, stop words removing, stemming, and TF-IDF weighting scheme.
I have some questions:
1- is it necessary to do a feature selection process in every text mining projects? 
2- is it necessary to estimate the similarity of documents, for example: by using Cosine similarity? 
or these two options are optional? 
and is StringToWordVector filter does some of these?

Answer (score 0):

1. It is not necessary. Nobody imposes you that step. But results usually improve with appropriate feature selection methods.
2. It is necesary if that is a goal of your project; it is not imposed by any means. The StringToWordVector filter only does that, convert your strings into wordVectors for further processing or analysis. It is up to you what you calculate from your data. If you need a similarity measure, then, cosine distance is a suitable measure.